# Python - Issue trying to get user input to convert to string and to prevent the user from entering in non decimal numbers

Tags: python, list, pycharm

Complete Python novice here working on a project we have been set to complete. I want the user to input a integer, which they can, I also want the program to not allow non int input into this. I tried mixing some things I found online, but seem to have broken my code and now I'm not sure why. Here is the code:

```py
student_list = []

def student_data():
    while True:
        student_name = input("Hello, please enter the student name, press 'q' to quit this program:")
        if str.lower(student_name) == "q":
            break
        student_list.append(student_name)
        for student_name in student_list:
            print("You entered:", student_name)

    while True:
        grade = (input("Please enter the student grade, enter 'q' to quit this program:"))
        if str.lower(grade) == 'q':
            return None
        while True
            try:
                student_grade = int(grade)
                return student_grade
            except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a grade between 1-10")
        student_list.append(grade)
        return student_data()
        for student_grade in student_list:
            print("You entered:", student_grade)


student_data()
print(student_list)
```

---

The previous code had this below but a string input would break the int(input), the goal is to make an input system that puts both the student name and grade into a list, then that list will go into a master list so groupings can be stored.

```py
student_list = []

def student_data():
    while True:
        student_name = input("Hello, please enter the student name, press 'q' to quit this program:")
        if str.lower(student_name) == "q":
            break
        student_list.append(student_name)
        for student_name in student_list:
            print("You entered:", student_name)

    while True:
        grade = int(input("Please enter the student grade, enter '11' to quit this program:"))
        if grade >= 11:
            break
        student_list.append(grade)
        for grade in student_list:
            print("You entered:", grade)


student_data()
print(student_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is missing after the third `while` statement, also `except` and `print` statements have the same indentation level.

You can use `try-except` without additional `while` loop, check if the input number is less then `11` and append the input the the list and if not break the while loop.

***Example***:

```
while True:
    try:
        grade = int(input("Please enter the student grade, enter '11' to quit this program:"))
        if grade >= 11:
            break
        student_list.append(grade)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input integer between 1-10")
```

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

flows answered your question appropriately.
Because I think you would like to ask for pairs of name and grade, I modified your program a little.

```
def student_data():
    student_list = []
    while True:
        # Ask for the name of the student
        student_name = input("Please enter the student name, press 'q' to quit this program: ")
        # When "q" is entered exit the loop.
        if student_name.lower() == 'q':
            break

        # Keep asking about the student's grade until a valid answer has been entered.
        while True:
            try:
                student_grade = int(input("Please enter a grade between 1-10: "))
                # If an error occurs during the conversion, the following lines
                # are not executed. A direct jump is made to the except block.

                if 0 < student_grade <= 10:
                    # If the value is within the expected limits add a tuple of
                    # name and grade to the list and exit the nested loop.
                    student_list.append((student_name, student_grade))
                    break
            except ValueError:
                # Ignore errors when converting the string to integer.
                pass

    # Return all pairs of name and grade as the result of the function.
    return student_list


for name, grade in student_data():
    print('You entered: ', name, grade)
```

Comment: Detlef, that looks really smart. I'm comparing it with mine now and will implement some of those suggestions